# Wrong DateTime in my Android App

Tags: android

Hiho
 could someone tell me why these Code doesn't work right?

```
private Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eintragen);
    this.dh = new DataHelper(this);

    EditText Datum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_meerwasser_wasserwerte_eintragen_datum);
    Datum.setText(dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

Each time i start the app it tells me: 03.7.2011
But the actuall date is 03.08.2011

I restarted the mobilephone and taked off the battery

With kind regards
Alex

Answer (score 2):

This is because Month will be considered from 0 and not from 1.
Try modifying your code like this,

```
private Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.eintragen);
this.dh = new DataHelper(this);

EditText Datum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_meerwasser_wasserwerte_eintragen_datum);
Datum.setText(dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+dateTime.get((Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"."+dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

}

So you have to increment the value of your month by one to get the current month.

Answer (score 1):

Add +1 with month.Because month starts from 0,not 1 in this Calendar.So for January you will get 0 rather than 1.

```
Datum.setText(dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+(dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"."+dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```